# one CNAME file for 2 distinct domains. gh-pages X namecheap

Tags: subdomain, web-hosting, github-pages

I have one project on GitHub, which exists in a private repository to which I am not the owner but a collaborator, it's my friends repo.

My goal is to make a landing page for our stie, and accordingly, as we've purchased the domains from NameCheap I followed [this tutorial](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9645/2208/how-do-i-link-my-domain-to-github-pages).

The problem is, we have two domains, one is `swopular.de` the other is `swopular.com`.

My idea was to put both of these in the CNAME file like so:

**CNAME**

```
swopular.de
swopular.com
```

but now when I try to access the site I get the following error:

```
404

There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

If you're trying to publish one, read the full documentation to learn how to set up GitHub Pages for your repository, organization, or user account
```

Something that aroused my suspicion in the tutorial I posted above was this step, on the NameCheap server I should...

```
Here you will need to create three records for your domain: 

- A record for @ pointing to 192.30.252.153
- A record for @ pointing to 192.30.252.154
- CNAME record for www pointing to your username.github.io (username should be replaced with your actual GitHub account username):
```

There I put `username.github.io` put the project that I want to create the site for actually lives in a repository which is a subdomain of that- but NameCheap won't let me enter a subdomain into that field, something like `username.github.io/XXX`

Maybe someone else with more experience in web development might know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CNAME` file of Github Pages only support 1 CNAME. (https://help.github.com/articles/about-supported-custom-domains/)

What I would recommend doing is picking one domain to be the primary. Since `de` is a country specific TLD and `com` is generic, I would choose `com`.

To allow your domain to be hosted at `www.swopular.com` and redirect `swopular.com` to the `www` subdomain, the `CNAME` file of Github Pages should only include `www.swopular.com`. The DNS records associated with it should be the ones that you mentioned,

```
- A record for @ pointing to 192.30.252.153
- A record for @ pointing to 192.30.252.154
- CNAME record for www pointing to your username.github.io (username should be replaced with your actual GitHub account username):
```

The server side should take care of adding the additional extension to the `CNAME` record, only include the `[username].github.io` in the `CNAME` record

For the `de` domain, I would recommend using Namecheap's HTTP redirect service. (https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/77/how-do-i-set-up-a-url-redirect-for-a-domain) You can then redirect both the root `de` and the `www.swopular.de` to `www.swopular.com`

Comment: I shouldn't need A records if I only want to use a subdomain (other than www) for my GhP, right? (as I don't expect bla.com to redirect to blog.bla.com because bla.com is a generic landing page)

Comment: @rudolfovic yup, you can just use CNAMEs if you want redirect only blog.bla.com.